# How to set back button on NavigationController? (Material iOS framework)

Tags: cosmicmind

This question is specific to the NavigationController in the Material iOS framework by CosmicMind. https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material

It looks like the backButtonImage is a public property

```
public var backButtonImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        if nil == backButtonImage {
            backButtonImage = MaterialIcon.arrowBack
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to set it properly.

```
            (navigationBar as! NavigationBar).backButtonImage = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.ChevronLeft, textColor: colorKit.headerTitleText, size: CGSizeMake(30,30))
```

The framework doesn't include the Material icons, so the back button appears as an empty button by default, which might be confusing to people.

Answer (score 0):

In Material 1.37.0, you can do this:

```
(navigationBar as? NavigationBar)?.backButtonImage = UIImage(named: "ic_icon_name")
```